# How virtual address is translated to disk address?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture

In case of page fault,the corresponding page has to be fetched from disk. As we know disk is collection of blocks which follow linear block addressing, how the virtual address for the particular page is translated to list of linear block addresses which contains the blocks of that page,so that those blocks can be moved from disk to main memory?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the OS. Linux systems usually have a swap partition for this. Another approach are swap files stored on a disk file system. 
A simple implementation would store the linear block address (LBA) in a hash table with virtual address as key. Each process would such a hash table. During a page fault, a simple lookup in the hash table reveals the LBA of the page.